# one jar file execute but the other jar won't execute

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to make a chat program. everything works fine when I run the program in netbeans. But when I do a build only my client side won't execute my jar file. The Server side jar file is executing when I double click on it.

From the command line I got this error 
no main manifest attribute, in C:\Users\J\Documents\NetBeansProjects\chatC\dist\chatC.jar

But there is a manifest in the root folder of chatC. And it is exactly the same manifest as in the Server side folder (same text(Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build) same place in the folder).

I also tried to do a clean and build. that doesn't help

client side is not starting the jar file

```
C:.
│   build.xml
│   manifest.mf
│
├───build
│   │   built-jar.properties
│   │
│   ├───classes
│   │   └───main
│   │           Client.class
│   │           GuiC.class
│   │
│   ├───empty
│   └───generated-sources
│       └───ap-source-output
├───dist
│       chatC.jar
│       README.TXT
│
├───nbproject
│   │   build-impl.xml
│   │   genfiles.properties
│   │   project.properties
│   │   project.xml
│   │
│   └───private
│           private.properties
│           private.xml
│
└───src
    └───main
            Client.java
            GuiC.java
```

server side starts the jar the file

```
C:.
│   build.xml
│   manifest.mf
│
├───build
│   │   built-jar.properties
│   │
│   ├───classes
│   │   └───main
│   │           Gui.class
│   │           Server.class
│   │
│   ├───empty
│   └───generated-sources
│       └───ap-source-output
├───dist
│       chat.jar
│       README.TXT
│
├───nbproject
│   │   build-impl.xml
│   │   genfiles.properties
│   │   project.properties
│   │   project.xml
│   │
│   └───private
│           config.properties
│           private.properties
│           private.xml
│
└───src
    └───main
            Gui.java
            Server.java
```

**solution**
I unpacked my client jar file. and compared the manifest with the serverside(which was working) I missed Main-Class: main.GuiC in my manifest. 
I opened my chatC.jar in winrar and copy paste the main.GuiC in my manifest after that it worked

Comment: *client side is not starting the jar file *: what does that mean? What are you doing **precisely** to start the application, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead, **precisely**?

Comment: _"Main-Class will be added automatically by build"_ I'm curious if it's adding the server's main class instead of client's main class as the entry point.  Can you open the file inside the jar and see what it says?

Comment: When double click on the chatC.jar it won't start my gui. And if I try through the command line I get the manifest error.  I expected that gui starts

Comment: @phflack what do you mean open the file inside the jar ? You mean properties-jar ? It are two differents projects. It isn't possible that my server side is building in my client ? output of properties-jar C\:\\Users\\J\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\chatC=

Comment: Well, what's different from the two jar files that makes only one of them work?  If it's complaining about the manifest, maybe you should open them and see what their contents are.  You can easily look inside a jar file by renaming it to a zip file

Comment: If the class path is missing in one but not the other, make them match and see if it works.  And do you know if it works if you build the jar file manually or with the jar command?

Comment: I missed Main-Class: so I added Main-Class: main.GuiC. And it is still not working. How do I pack my Manifest and main back in my jar file ?

Comment: Copy and paste should work fine

Comment: *"When double click on the chatC.jar it won't start my gui."* Run it from the command line and look for error reports. Make sure the code does not catch then ignore exceptions.

Comment: I can not copy paste my Meta-inf and main in my jar file ? How do i rebuild my jar file with the updated manifest ?

Comment: @AndrewThompson It still gives me the error no manifest from the cli

Comment: alright I got it working. I will edit my first post for the solution thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Curious, why wouldn't you be able to copy and paste?  If you created the file, you should have adequate permissions